# How to find $K,W,S$ in the Mostow decomposition theorem?

Tags: matrices, decomposition-theorem

The Mostow decomposition theorem states:
Let $Z$ a nonsingular complex matrix, then $Z$ can be factored as:
$$Z=We^{iK}e^S$$ where: $W$ is unitary, $K$ is real and skew symmetric and $S$ is real and symmetric.
Given a complex matrix $Z$ how is it possible to find $K,S,W$?
Thanks

Comment: This looks like a variant of the polar decomposition of a matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Answer (score -1):

Check this paper. It gives a way of explicitly determining these factors.
 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379513005612